# Where does extra 'p' in NSManagedObjectID come from?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, game-center, nsincrementalstore

I am forming an `NSManagedObjectID` like this:

```
 NSManagedObjectID *objectID = [store newObjectIDForEntity: entityForPlayer 
                                           referenceObject: GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.playerID];
```

`store` is an `NSIncrementalStore`. In the debugger `GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer.playerID` looks like `G:12345678` but `objectID` looks like `<x-coredata://<UUID>/Player/pG:12345678>`.

Where does the extra `p` (before the verbatim player ID) come from? It apparently does not show up with other entity types, which also use `NSString`s as reference objects.

Comment: What's the programming language here? You're probably missing a language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Educated guess, because it's an implementation detail:

The `p` means something like permanent, because the object has been saved to the store. i.e. `[objectID isTemporaryID] == NO`.

It'll be a `t` if the objects hasn't been saved yet. i.e. `[objectID isTemporaryID] == YES`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that is apparently does not show up with other entity types (please see updated question). I'll check `p` for permanent and `t` for temporary and will accept your answer, if this is it.